# How to build a basic product profile in WooCommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm really new into WooCommerce and not an expert in WooCommerce, I have developed custom WordPress themes but not WooCommerce.

I have been trying to use different codes to display certain things like Attributes, Add to cart button, title, etc. I have managed to do almost everything, I had the Add to Cart button but I need to have sizes in a dropdown (i already have the attributes created) so my button just converted itself into "Select Options" when I made this product "Variable". So now I'm pretty confused

```
<h1>
  <?php echo $product->get_title(); ?>
</h1>
<div class="amount">$
  <?php echo $product->get_price ()?>
</div>    
<p class="product-description">
  <?php echo $product->get_description(); ?>
</p>
<!-- Add to Cart Button -->
<?php  
global $product;
echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link',
sprintf( '<a href="%s" rel="nofollow" data-product_id="%s" data-product_sku="%s" class="button %s product_type_%s">%s</a>',
esc_url( $product->add_to_cart_url() ),
esc_attr( $product->id ),
esc_attr( $product->get_sku() ),
$product->is_purchasable() ? 'add_to_cart_button' : '',
esc_attr( $product->product_type ),
esc_html( $product->add_to_cart_text() )
),
$product );
?>
<?php
$subheadingvalues = get_terms('size', array(
'hide_empty' => false,
));
?> 
<select>
  <?php foreach ($subheadingvalues as $subheadingvalue): ?>
  <option value="<?php echo $subheadingvalue->name; ?>">
    <?php echo $subheadingvalue->name; ?>
  </option>
  <?php endforeach;?>
</select>
```

This is how it looks now: http://prntscr.com/oqbyry
This is what I'm trying to achieve: http://prntscr.com/oqbzb6

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Sorry if this is not well formatted, it's my first post.

Answer (score 0):

I corrected your code. Can you please check and let me know if it's working.

```
<h1><?php echo $product->get_title(); ?></h1>
                  <div class="amount">$<?php echo $product->get_price ()?></div>    
                  <p class="product-description"><?php echo $product->get_description(); ?></p>

                  <!-- Add to Cart Button -->
                  <?php  
                    global $product;

                    echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link',
                        sprintf( '<a href="%s" rel="nofollow" data-product_id="%s" data-product_sku="%s" class="button %s product_type_%s">%s</a>',
                            esc_url( $product->add_to_cart_url() ),
                            esc_attr( $product->id ),
                            esc_attr( $product->get_sku() ),
                            $product->is_purchasable() ? 'add_to_cart_button' : '',
                            esc_attr( $product->product_type ),
                            esc_html( $product->add_to_cart_text() )
                        ),
                    $product );
                  ?>
        <?php 
        global $product;
        $handle=new WC_Product_Variable($product->get_id());
                $variations1=$handle->get_children();
                echo '<select>';
                foreach ($variations1 as $value) {
                $single_variation=new WC_Product_Variation($value);
                    echo '<option  value="'.$value.'">'.implode(" / ", $single_variation->get_variation_attributes()).'-'.get_woocommerce_currency_symbol().$single_variation->price.'</option>';
        }
        echo '</select>';
            ?>
```

Comment: Hey Pullata thank you for taking your time to help me thru this! Select now looks better, but still call to action says Select Options
Screenshot: http://prntscr.com/ore9qx
Thoughts?

Comment: Can you provide me your web credentials to check and fix the issue?

Comment: Sure! is there any way to direct message you? thank you!

Comment: This is my mail I'd 'pullata.praveen@gmail.com'